# Compositor Blows out Image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, color-management, .exr

I am exporting into half EXR's with ACES_cg (would full help?)
[image]
[image]

But as you see in the second image the compositor output is blown out. But when I take a look at the EXR it is not blown out but still does not go over 1 why?
[image]

Can anybody explain to me why and how to fix it or is it just a limitation of Blender? And Thank you

Here are my Color managment settings:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my fault I messed up the compositing the denoise node was not set to HDR and flattened everything